# Limit a multidimensional array response

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, limit

Having 3 multidimensional arrays, to whom I do a `foreach` how can I limit the multidimensional response inside foreach from **X** items to lets say **20**.

Code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($value->channel->item as $item)
{
    $data['data'][$keySection]['item1'][$i]['url']   = $item->url;
    $data['data'][$keySection]['item1'][$i]['title'] = $item->title;
    $data['data'][$keySection]['item1'][$i]['img']   = $item->thumb;
    $i++;
}
```

where `$value` is contained within

```
foreach ($homeData as $keySection => $valueSection)
{
    foreach($valueSection as $key => $value)
    {
        switch ($key)
        {
```

I've tried aplying some `for`s both within `foreach ($value->channel->item as $item)` as outside but I just can't get it to work properly, I get either doubled results or not working at all.

How can I make this work??

**Edit:**
`$i` has nothing to do with it...  I need to limit `$value->channel->item` where `item` contains X results

**Edit2**:
`$i` is for `$homeData` where `$homeData` contains three values and each and one of those will later contain 3 different values of `$value->channel->item` so if item contains 20 results, will be 3x20 = 60 and $i is ment to separate each 20 results...

**Edit3**:
ok, now I get it... sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Do you mean that you need to execute till $i = 20 ??

Comment: no, `$i` has nothing to do with it...

Comment: So what do you want is to show just 20 item s right.that's what i asked

Comment: Then my answer is good for you. It does limit the processing of $item to 20 iterations..

Comment: `$i` is for `$homeData` where home data contains three values and each and one of those will later contain 3 different values of `$value->channel->item`

Comment: Then you should not increase the $i inside that foreach too I think.. this will make $i get bigger everytime you process 1 $item.

Comment: ok, now I get it... sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: :-) Can you accept the right answer for you then?

Comment: yes, but I would appreciate if you were to cancel your vote down to... (also edit your answer, so I can give the vote up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you start the foreach, add:

```
if($i > 19) {
    break;
}
```

This checks if $i is greater than 19 (which means 20 iterations) and then breaks this foreach loop. More information about break, [here](http://nl2.php.net/break).

Comment: Why not? You are increasing $i everytime an item is inserted to $data, so then we can also use that variable to check for the amount of inserts you did to that array.. If it has nothing to do with it, make your question more clear to us.

Comment: Does my adjusted answer make more sense?

Comment: @w0rldart if the object `$value->channel->item` contains 50 items then $i would reach 49

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($value->channel->item as $item)
{
     if($i > 19) {
       break;
     }
     $data['data'][$keySection]['item1'][$i]['url']   = $item->url;
     $data['data'][$keySection]['item1'][$i]['title'] = $item->title;
     $data['data'][$keySection]['item1'][$i]['img']   = $item->thumb;
     $i++;
}
```

This will give you 20 items.

Hope this is what you want :)

Comment: If $i goes to 3 only then your loop will be executed 4 times. Then how can you get 20 items. Else make the question more clear

Comment: I am not getting the point. What are you trying to achieve here. If $i will go only three, then how you have 20 items . You have only 3

Comment: This is same as what i did. What is the difference

Comment: You used a new variable $count. I used $i . If $i only goes till 3 how could count goes till 12 or 20.. Please understand the PHP basic concepts first

Comment: What do you mean. What is the point in declaring $count since it is same as $i. Just using another memory location. Why are you doing that if you can do it using $i itself

Comment: We don't get why $i doesn't have anything to do with it because $i in your example has the same value as $count. So it would be way more efficient to use $i instead of using a new variable. Learning PHP basic would be welcome, I join @Sabari on that one.

Comment: It would be better if you could use this link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/  to study some basic things of PHP

Comment: ok, now I get it... sorry for the misunderstanding ... no need of giving me php basics links... everybody does mistakes when tired

Comment: +1 because it is the right answer and I don't understand why it has been downvoted.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I too don't know :(